# Are Asp.Net Core 3.1 IHost implementations designed to be restartable?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

If I have a `Host` instance build with `HostBuilder` and I call `StartAsync()` and then `StopAsync()` and then some time in the future I call StartAsync() again, is it supposed to work?

I looked in the ASP.NET Core Source Code and both `Host` and `KestrelServer` are written in a way that suggests that you are not supposed to reuse them after calling StopAsync();

The problem is that it throws an exception - it looks like it does not take restarting into consideration: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L44

Are `Host` instances restartable?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, they are restartable, or at least, there's nothing technically stopping you from calling `StartAsync` again. However, there's a practical limitation here. What you have at the lowest level is a console app, which just runs `Program.Main` and then returns. The app doesn't keep running; it exits. Among other things, `StartAsync`, starts listening on sockets, which causes the app to "hang" in the sense that it can't continue and exit. When you call `StopAsync`, this listening stops, and then the app will immediately continue on and eventually exit. Once the console app has exited, you obviously can't call `StartAsync` again, because there's nothing running any more. You have to somehow cause the app to hang after calling `StopAsync` and then call `StartAsync` again, but that makes no real functional sense. Further, it makes no sense really to stop anything that you intend to start again sometime later. If nothing is happening, it's not really doing anything. It's sitting on some small amount of base resources, but if that's a concern, you're far to resource-contrained to begin with, as it's like less than 100MB or RAM, and virtually no CPU cycles.

Comment: Well, I have a console app that does something else that is long running and I want to start an HTTP server and do some work and then stop it and then start it again.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make any sense either. The only reason to have an HTTP server running is for *external* interaction, i.e. something else being able to make a request. By definition, you can't just start up a server when that external thing needs it, because it's external. If you have enough control to coordinate this, then it shouldn't be something you're coordinating in the first place. It should just all be part of the same app.

Comment: The problem is that it throws an exception, I found the source code and it looks like it does not take restarting into consideration. https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/3.1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L44

Comment: my question is 'is it restartable?' not 'does it make sense to restart it.' :)

Comment: This is smelling like an XY problem. You've got problem X that you've decided to solve with Y, but Y doesn't work. Instead of asking about X, your actual problem, you're asking about Y, which isn't even a good solution to X, in the first place. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Restart a `Host` instance that is started and then stopped. My question is (as the title says) 'Are Asp.Net Core 3.1 IHost implementations designed to be restartable?' .

You can answer 'yes' or 'no' and argument yourself. Telling me that my question does not make sense is not helpful. :)

Comment: That is the question, because the team apparently made no effort to ensure you could restart it because it makes no sense that you ever would. Again, servers are things that are meant to *stay* running, because they provide a service for external processes which could make requests at any time. If you have enough knowledge and control to ensure that the server is only running when the external process needs it, then you're bleeding your domains, and the external thing is not truly external, and shouldn't be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212701/discussion-between-hristo-kolev-and-chris-pratt).